# Finding all the index corruptions in the entire Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, index, corruption, duplication

There is DB with unknown amount of corrupted unique indexes.
Currently I discover them one by one when I try `REINDEX DATABASE CONCURRENTLY <db_name>`, handle the specific duplication violation (manipulating data, mainly delete the duplications using scripts), reindex the specific table or index, and continue to the next index (again only right after I discover it using `REINDEX DATABASE CONCURRENTLY`).

Not mentioning that each time I get indexes with the '_ccnew' suffix, that AFAIK are indexes that were tried to be created by a previous reindex concurrently but couldn’t be done, usually because they are violating a uniqueness check.
The failed attempts to reindex concurrently will sit in there and should be dropped manually.

**Concurrent** reindex is used in order to prevent a shutdown.

I want to reduce those "roundtrips" of searching the next violation and wonder if there is a more efficient way to get a general data about the status of all the index corruptions or unique violations that a Postgres DB has.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [amcheck](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/amcheck.html) extension to check a B-tree index for corruption. For other index types, there is no alternative to rebuilding the index.

You can run the following to check an index for corruption:

```
SELECT bt_index_check('indexname'::regclass);
```

That can be automatized to run against all the indexes in your database:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   indid oid;
   msg text;
BEGIN
   FOR indid IN
      SELECT i.oid
      FROM pg_class AS i
         JOIN pg_am ON pg_am.oid = i.relam
      WHERE pg_am.amname = 'btree'
        AND i.relkind = 'i'
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         PERFORM bt_index_check(indid);
      EXCEPTION WHEN index_corrupted THEN
         GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
         RAISE WARNING 'Index "%" is currupted: %', indid::regclass, msg;
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

`bt_index_check()` has an optional second parameter; if you supply `TRUE`, the check will take much longer, but verify that all table rows are indexed.

Note that `bt_index_check()` does not cover all kinds of index corruption. There is also `bt_index_parent_check()`, which tests more thoroughly, but requires a `SHARE` lock that prevents concurrent data modification.